# Is there a way to add lines to .bashrc without permission to access?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I have `ssh`ed into another computer, on which I’ll be working. In order to access the tools I need, I’m supposed to “go into my .bashrc file” and add two lines:

```
eval 'path/to/file/setup.sh'
```

AND

```
source 'a/different/path/setup.sh'
```

Unfortunately, I get a “permission denied” error when I try to open `.bashrc`. I’ve tried using `sudo`, but I get a “user is not in the sudoers file”. I’ve also tried using `su` first, but I get “su: authentication failure”.

Is there a way to accomplish what I need without access to `.bashrc`? I’m in a bit of a pinch and no ones available for some time.

Comment: "when I try to open .bashrd" ... Did you try to run `.bashrc` instead of editing it?

Comment: Yes, I cannot run it either

Comment: Can you ad the access flags of your `.bashrc` and home directory (`ls -l ~/.bashrc` and `ls -ld ~`) to you question?  (I'm also a bit surprised by this `eval ....` but this is another question)

Comment: No, I'm not asking you to run it. How exactly did you try to open it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a pinch, just run these commands manually until someone can give you access.

Adding them to `.bashrc` just means that they will run automatically when you log in or open a new shell.